# What is the relation between optimality theory and AI?

Tags: neural-networks, applications, comparison

How do the basic components [optimality theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimality_theory) apply to artificial intelligence?

How is optimality theory related to neural network research?

Comment: Here's a paper due to Schmidhuber which is arguably the last word on optimality and AI: http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0309048

Answer (score -1):

In AI, Optimality Theory provides a formal framework for modeling decision-making processes and optimizing outcomes.

In relation to neural network research, OT has been used to develop models that mimic human cognitive processes, such as perception, memory, and decision-making.